# Is it possible to view the source of a malicious pdf?

Tags: malware, javascript, avast

I am using osx mavericks.  Avast alerted to a file that was in a hidden spotlight directory that had random-looking characters as a name with a .txt extension. It identified as a javascript trojan. I put the file in quarantine and restored it to the desktop and I remember the original file, when I downloaded it, was a pdf. In either its, current form (txt), or the original pdf is there a way to see what the source would look like? I assume it is in a compiled-type form, so can a program find and rebuild the source? How could one even find the potential malicious code in a pdf?

Comment: I am going to guess the file claims to be a pdf but its not actually one, if thats the case, no there is no way to convert it.

Comment: @ramhound: it was a pdf that worked fine in any reader. Something, avast or the OS or trojan itself, put a version of the file in hidden spotlight folder as a .txt version.